# Searching file name with * regular expression in C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a list of files in WP7 isolated storage which has space character in the file name e.g. "My File Name 1.dat". I want to get all these files name in a string[]. I have used the following code but I am not getting the file names:

```
string searchPattern = "FolderName" + "\\*";
string[] fileList = store.GetFileNames(searchPattern);
```

Please help!

Comment: Are you sure, your folder "FolderName" has any file in it ?

Comment: Can you check your running folder? maybe the path is wrong

Comment: Try with `"*.*"` instead of just `"*"`

Comment: Can you use the isolated storage explorer to check if the files are actually present: http://wp7explorer.codeplex.com/

Comment: I have checked with the isolated storage tool "ISETool" and everything is there. The folder and the files are created successfully.

Comment: @PedroLamas I have tried with what you told but not working.

Answer (score 0):

Take the quotes off of your FolderName variable to make it:

string searchPattern = FolderName + "\*";

Comment: Try GetDirectoryNames() and see if your folder is found.